# K8s: app.kubernetes.io instance label purpose

Tags: kubernetes

These are recommended labels:

```
app.kubernetes.io/name
app.kubernetes.io/instance
app.kubernetes.io/version
app.kubernetes.io/component
app.kubernetes.io/part-of
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by
```

I don't quite figure out what `app.kubernetes.io/instance` is for.

Could you provide any useful examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A generic application `name` can have multiple `instance`s.

Say if an application used `nginx` to serve different types of content, so each type of nginx can be scaled independantly:

```
app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx

app.kubernetes.io/instance: static-01

app.kubernetes.io/instance: img-02

app.kubernetes.io/instance: dynamic-05
```

They are only recommendations though so you can use them how you want. In small scale clusters you might not have a need to make `name` and `instance` different.

See [Applications And Instances Of Applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/#applications-and-instances-of-applications)

> An application can be installed one or more times into a Kubernetes cluster and, in some cases, the same namespace. For example, wordpress can be installed more than once where different websites are different installations of wordpress.
>
> The name of an application and the instance name are recorded separately. For example, WordPress has a `app.kubernetes.io/name` of `wordpress` while it has an instance name, represented as `app.kubernetes.io/instance` with a value of `wordpress-abcxzy`. This enables the application and instance of the application to be identifiable. Every instance of an application must have a unique name.

Comment: Could you provide any example according an straightforward microservices architecture. I mean, an springboot service smaple...

Comment: It's less likely to come up in a microservice environment as the design pattern dictates small specific applications. An example could be multiple environments  running the the same namespace.   A service named `query-x`  could have a `query-x-dev` `query-x-int` `query-x-qa` instance all running.

Comment: Or if the `query-x` service ran in two configurations.  `query-x-queue` and `query-x-nanomsg`